# How to convert these inline style in html into react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

Hi Inside the html people use these kind of styles to animate.
I am actually following the pen from alphadex [Link](https://codepen.io/alphardex/pen/YzWypem).

I never see this kind of writing in HTML before

```
<div class="lines">
    <div class="line" style="--i: 1;"></div>
    <div class="line" style="--i: 2;"></div>
    <div class="line" style="--i: 3;"></div>
    <div class="line" style="--i: 4;"></div>
  </div>
```

I am trying to change it into the react component. I can change the classname but
i don't know how to convert the style?

Here is the react component

```
<div className="lines">
    <div className="line"></div>
    <div className="line"></div>
    <div className="line"></div>
    <div className="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried this?

<div className="line" style={{ --i: '1' }}>
</div>

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can do inline styling in React like this:

```
<div className="lines">
   <div className="line" style={{--i: 1}}></div>
   <div className="line" style={{--i: 2}}></div>
   <div className="line" style={{--i: 3}}></div>
   <div className="line" style={{--i: 4}}></div>
</div>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_css.asp

Edit: Maybe you have to try `{{--i: "1"}}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

wrap them as classes

```
.i-1 {
    --i: 1;
}
.i-2 {
    --i: 2;
}
 ....

<div className="lines">
    <div className="line i-1"></div>
    <div className="line i-2"></div>
    <div className="line i-3"></div>
    <div className="line i-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add {{}} to your style. And convert css properties to camelcase.Here is example:

```
<div
            style={{
              width: '100%',
              backgroundColor: '#f1f1f1',
              display: 'flex',
              justifyContent: 'center',
            }}
          >
            test
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert html inline style to react inline style like:

```
<div className="line" style={{"--i": 1}}></div>
<div className="line" style={{"--i": 2}}></div>
```